# Google Calendar API - Can't add google meets to event

Tags: google-calendar-api

i'm using a service account to add events to my calendar, 1 month ago it was working with the code below, then after sometime it started to give me the error: 'invalid conference data type', i removed 'conferenceDataVersion' field and it started working again. Now it doesn't work both ways. When i test it from the Calendar API page it works fine with the same parameters, but on my app it's not working.
The event is added succesfully, but no google meets link is created.
I think that maybe i can't create an event of the type "hangoutsMeet" on a service account, while i was testing it worked because i was creating it from the same account. BTW i still can't figure out why it was working fine one month ago, nothing has changed. I was using the exact same configurations and code and i managed to create an event and to add a google meet conference to that evet.

```
calendar.events.insert( {
            "calendarId" : 'primary',
            "conferenceDataVersion": 1,
            "resource":{
                "end": {
                    "dateTime" : endDate.toISOString(),
                    'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin'
                },
                "start": {
                    "dateTime" : startDate.toISOString(),
                    'timeZone': 'Europe/Berlin'
                },
                "conferenceData": {
                    "createRequest": {
                        "requestId": randomstring,
                        "conferenceSolutionKey": {
                            "type": "hangoutsMeet"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What language are you using to make this request? Are you using [domain-wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) on the service account?

Comment: i am using nodejs, with the nodejs client library. Yes i have used domain-wide-delegation on the service account, though i dont 't have gsuite on the main account, i don't know if thats the problem. Still i can't understand why it was working at the beginning, it has worked from half january till the first days of february.

Comment: Do you mean that you dont have Google Workspace in the account using the service account? Also what was the last date you can remember this piece of code worked correctly? With this I am trying to figure out if any [recent update on the Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/releases) might have affected you.

Comment: Yes. The last time it worked was about the first week of february, as i said i removed conferenceDataVersion and it was working again(not sure if it was that one), then again not working both ways, at the beginning of march

Comment: If you change your service account in your Node.js code with an admin account instead do you get the same behaviour?

Comment: No, i have tried with the main account and it works, it adds the Google Meets event

Comment: I am a bit confused at how you have set this up between regular and workspace accounts. Can you provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I think this is a problem with the client API: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/2387